# On submit, remote call php - why aren't $_POST values being posted?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So, I'm a bit in unfamiliar territory with json and remote calls but the url and datatype  is correct and... it is clearly arriving at target. BUT.!

It's a very simple form with 3 visible and 2 hidden fields.

```
<form id="subChange" action="#" method="POST">  
    <div style="clear:both;">first name</div>  
    <div>
       <input id="fart" type="text" style="margin:4px;width:90%;" name="newFirst" value="" data-validetta="required,characters,remote[check_update]">
    </div>  last name<BR>
    <div>
       <input type="text" style="margin:4px;width:90%;" name="newLast" value="" data-validetta="required,characters,remote[check_update]">
    </div>  eMail<BR>
    <div>
       <input type="hidden" name="oldName" value="Conor" data-validetta="remote[check_update]">
    </div>  
    <div>
       <input type="hidden" name="oldEmail" value="cburkeg@gmail.com" data-validetta="remote[check_update]">
    </div>  
    <div>
       <input type="text" style="margin:4px;width:90%;" name="newEmail" value="" data-validetta="required,email,remote[check_update]">
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:12px">  
       <input type="submit" name="sub_change" value="change it" data-validetta="remote[check_update]">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#subChange").validetta({
            realTime : true,
            bubbleLoc:"right",
            onValid : function( event ){
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#changeDIV").html("thanks Conor <P>Your subscription has been updated");
            },
            remote : { check_update : { type : "POST", url : "checkNewsUpdate.php", datatype : "json" }}
        });
     })
</script>
```

With fields filled we test Submit; name='sub_change'  value='change it'

```
if (isset($_POST['sub_change'])) {
    $count = count($_POST);
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); //... write to file, etc.
}
```

output -

```
$count: 1  
$postdata: sub_change=change+it
```

What happened to the other fields?

My only current working solution is to set each field with the remote call and set a $_POST validation (done auto., in real time) for each input which writes to a remote file. On submit we then call the contents of that file. Only trouble is it misses the 2 hidden files - there is no auto trigger :(

This is a clumsy work-around (that doesn't even work).
I thought about setting the hidden fields as an ID but getting the value with PHP is a trial. There must be something real simple I am missing here.

Comment: you're posting JSON so the data won't be in $_POST. and/or you aren't posting to a file - just to `#`

Comment: OK. On a learning curve here. So how best to extract that data - in a PHP file? parse? json_decode? post to '#' works fine as the js url directs it.

Comment: Currently trying json_decode but [sorry my ineptitude] what is the _data_ name? json_decode( data, dataTypeBoolean, depth, options )

Comment: Is there some way to test for the presence of json data? as in file_get_contents("php://input"); to review $_POST array. The data is being fed through validetta.js (form validation) and I am not clear how to get the data name.